# Why can't I use any C# 10 features?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I installed .NET 6. Using Visual Studio 2019.
Checked .net version by typing dotnet --info. Everything is okay.
However, when I create a new project in VS, I don't see .NET 6 in a dropdown menu. It's .NET 5 by default. Nevertheless, changed the version in .csproj file. The content of the file is:

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

The problem is I can't use any new C# 10 features. Can't even change C# version in Advanced properties:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnqdR.png)

Comment: you must be missing right frameworks. try downloading VS2022 and see if it works.

Comment: What does "I installed .net 6" mean?> What *exactly* did you install? What frameworks settings do you have on the Application page of those settings? See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 - only certain preview versions work on 2019, but people also come saying they "installed it" and it turns out they installed the runtime, not the SDK

Comment: VS2022 -> .NET 6 -> C#10

Comment: @CaiusJard I mean SDK 6.0.101 for Windows (x64).

Comment: You need 2022 for that one.. See "Visual Studio Support" header of https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0